# trying to understand cookies during post request

Tags: session, post, cookies

How does browser send back cookie to the server during post requests. How is this different than the form data that is sent during a post ?

Also are the values of cookies for a particular domain automatically sent back to the domain for all its subsequent requests ?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no different between how cookies are sent for GET and POST requests.

Form data is data such as fields from an HTML Form, eg. name, username, file, etc...

Any cookies sent back in a response from a domain will be sent back to the server in subsequent requests. This is true in web browsers at least, if you are doing this in code, you might have to write additional code to handle cookies.

This should work for AJAX calls made by your browser as well as full pages. Every request, be it full pages, images or AJAX calls will have the Cookies attached if they are going to an appropriate domain and path.

These primers on cookies and HTTP POST would be useful:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)

Comment: Kieran thanks for the answer. Thus this hold true for any ajax requests also ?